# add attribute column button is missing-Custom Grid

Tags: adminhtml, grid

I created my custom grid in an extension but I don't know if it is something with permission or not that a button is not showing up in grid customization:
[image]

it should have add attribute column like this:
[image]

controller:

```
class Lenmar_Lightbulbs_Adminhtml_LightbulbsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{
protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('lightbulbs/lightbulbs');
    }

public function indexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('lightbulbs/adminhtml_lightbulbs');
    $this->renderLayout();

}

public function gridAction()
    {

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('lightbulbs/adminhtml_lightbulbs_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }   


}
```

my cache is disabed and I reindexed it didn't help even I copy pasted my other extension which has this button and again rename everything it didn't work

I have the buttons comming from T:\app\code\community\BL\CustomGrid\Block\Widget\Grid\Columns\Config.php

here is the function:

```
public function getAddColumnButtonHtml()
{
    return parent::getButtonHtml($this->__('Add Attribute Column'), $this->getJsObjectName().'.addColumn();', 'scalable add');
}
```

also I can rename other ones and they will be changed in button text

also I found the condition! that when to show it:

```
   <?php if ($this->canDisplayColumnsConfig()): ?>
                                <?php if ($_gridModel->canHaveAttributeColumns()): ?>
                                    <span class="field-row">
                                        <?php echo $this->getAddColumnButtonHtml() ?>
                                    </span>
                                <?php endif ?>
```

I commented out this if condition and add attribute column showed up but I cannot do it it would affect other areas where add column shouldn't be there it seems I have some permission problem which I dont know how to figure out for this extension

Comment: Flush cache and reindex data then relogin once this may help.

Comment: Please add some code on how you implemented this.

Comment: my cache is disabled

Comment: Anna which part of extention you like to see? controller?grid? what?

Comment: If you make a random change to artificial properties is this reflected in your admin (lets say.. renaming one of the other buttons)?

Comment: where can I rename the buttons? I searched for add attribute column button text and it is in config.php and the path is app/code/community/bl/customgrid and also it is like that for other extensions  but it doesnt show up here

Comment: yes I renamed grid info now pleaaase tell me how to show add attribute column i am so done:((((((

Comment: look to see how grid info is added -- replicate that functionality!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:
I should add the type of grid and then it will be addable

T:\app\code\community\BL\CustomGrid\Model\Grid\Type\Product.php

```
public function isAppliableToGrid($type, $rewritingClassName)
{
return $type == 'lightbulbs/adminhtml_lightbulbs_grid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

app\code\community\BL\CustomGrid\Model\Grid\Type\Product.php

public function isAppliableToGrid($type, $rewritingClassName){

```
    return (($type == 'adminhtml/catalog_product_grid')
        || ($type == 'adminhtml/catalog_category_tab_product')
        || ($type == 'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_related')
        || ($type == 'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_upsell')
        || ($type == 'adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_crosssell')
        || ($type == 'lightbulbs/adminhtml_lightbulbs_grid'));
}
```